# Complex Empirical Orthogonal Function analysis on Propagating wave

Tags: waves, data-analysis

Since Complex EOF (CEOF) is doing hilbert transform before general EOF,
we can get four outputs in each mode.

1. Magnitude spatial pattern
2. Magnitude time series
3. Phase spatial pattern
4. Phase time series

I would like to ask that the spatial pattern in Magnitude and Phase are corresponding to "Phase velocity" or "Group velocity" ?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of where this technique is used (a link or so)? From what I can find, (C)EOF is mostly akin to principal component analysis, which is a dimensionality reduction technique. That has little to do with phase or group velocities...

Comment: @Erik The paper FYI : https://rmets.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/joc.1499

Comment: Also, I think my answer is simply depends on what data I get. As general, we often get the observational data with group velocity, then CEOF might give me the analysis about it.